# How to get sample from twitter stream and print to screen

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I'm trying to use the `twitter4j` library to get a random sample from the twitter stream and print the username and text of the tweet.

I'm not sure I understand the correct terminology as far as `OAuth` goes.  Is this something I need to get for my account or only if accessing other private accounts?

Here's my code:

```
package tweet1;

import java.io.IOException;

import twitter4j.Status;
import twitter4j.StatusDeletionNotice;
import twitter4j.StatusListener;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterStream;
import twitter4j.TwitterStreamFactory;
import twitter4j.auth.BasicAuthorization;

public class Twit4jEx1 {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        public static void main(String[] args) throws TwitterException, IOException{
//          BasicAuthorization ba1 = new BasicAuthorization("userName", "pword");
            ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();

            StatusListener listener = new StatusListener(){
                public void onStatus(Status status) {
                    System.out.println(status.getUser().getName() + " : " + status.getText());
                }
                public void onDeletionNotice(StatusDeletionNotice statusDeletionNotice) {}
                public void onTrackLimitationNotice(int numberOfLimitedStatuses) {}
                public void onException(Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                @Override
                public void onScrubGeo(long arg0, long arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            };
            TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory().getInstance();
            // sample() method internally creates a thread which manipulates TwitterStream and calls these adequate listener methods continuously.
            twitterStream.sample();
        }   
}
```

ConfigurationBuilder class

```
package tweet1;

import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
//import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;

public class ConfigurationBuilder {
    ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
      .setOAuthConsumerKey("***")
      .setOAuthConsumerSecret("***")
      .setOAuthAccessToken("***")
      .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("***");
    TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
    Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();
}
```

When I run `Twit4jEx1` I get the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
    Syntax error on token "setDebugEnabled", = expected after this token

    at tweet1.ConfigurationBuilder.<init>(ConfigurationBuilder.java:9)
    at tweet1.Twit4jEx1.main(Twit4jEx1.java:21)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you looked at this -> http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html

Comment: And this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7547470/twitter4j-twitterstream-doesnt-get-all-tweets  Apart from this -> http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc/index.html

Comment: @AnujKulkarni: yes, that's where I got the code from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You class ConfigurationBuilder is trying to run code in an initialization block instead of in a constructor or method.

I think you meant to have something like:

```
public class MyConfigurationBuilder {
    private ConfigurationBuilder cb; 
    private Twitter twitter;

    public MyConfigurationBuilder() {
      cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
      cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
        .setOAuthConsumerKey("***")
        .setOAuthConsumerSecret("***")
        .setOAuthAccessToken("***")
        .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("***");
      TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
      twitter = tf.getInstance();
    }
}
```

And then you can add appropriate getters or something.  Make sure you use MyConfigurationBuilder in your main funciton.