# TwitterFactory().getInstance() get no method suitable

Tags: java, twitter4j

i am trying to build a simple application that related to twitter. i have read so many tutorial about it, but i got an error in a very early step of code.

```
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance(txtUsername.getText(),arrayToString(txtPassword.getPassword()));
```

where the  txtUsername is an edit text and txtPassword is a passwordField.
arrayToString method is this

```
 private String arrayToString(char[] arr)
{
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
        result.append(arr[i]);
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

and here is the error

```
no suitable method found for getInstance(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
method twitter4j.TwitterFactory.getInstance(twitter4j.auth.Authorization) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method twitter4j.TwitterFactory.getInstance(twitter4j.auth.AccessToken) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method twitter4j.TwitterFactory.getInstance() is not applicable
```

### (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

Thank you so much, any help will be very great..

Comment: Error is correct because getInstacne method takes AccessToken or Autherization instance(http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/TwitterFactory.html)....why dont you take a look at the following samples...http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html

Comment: thank you so much for your respond :), i am looking this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2-iz5CduZdw , and it show no error :(, i already write the same code,and follow the right step

Comment: Then it seems your twitter4j API jar is different from the one used in the video.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12097247/how-to-get-sample-from-twitter-stream-and-print-to-screen) post helps a little...

Comment: i'll try to use the other twitter4j

Comment: Thanks all, i just use the same api with the one in the video... thanks all :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getInstance` method you are trying to use doesn't exist in Twitter4J. If you look at the [javadoc](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/TwitterFactory.html#TwitterFactory%28%29) you will see that three `getInstance` methods are available:

```
Twitter getInstance()
Twitter getInstance(AccessToken accessToken)
Twitter getInstance(Authorization auth)
```

That's why your compiler is complaining about the use of:

```
getInstance(String, String)
```

Comment: thanks for the info, i solved it already. anyway i got new lesson from you.. thank you